# Couldn't find package gitolite on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, apt, packages, gitolite

I've been following [this tutorial](http://computercamp.cdwilson.us/git-gitolite-git-daemon-gitweb-setup-on-ubunt) and I'm stuck on

`sudo apt-get install gitolite`

with the error

`Couldn't find package gitolite`

I've been Googling around for a while now, no one else seems to have this problem so it's probably a trivial matter... I'm not sure if it's a line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` I need to add, or if the package just isn't available for Ubuntu 10.04.

How do I fix the fact that it can't find the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would be simpler to simply grab the source on GitHub:

```
git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
# or
git clone https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite.git
```

(like this [tutorial explains](http://www.philwhln.com/install-gitolite-to-manage-your-git-repositories), also detailed in the official [Gitolite Installation page](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html))
There were already previous issues with `apt-get install gitolite`, like [in this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/gitolite/browse_thread/thread/7857a2fb3e71425b).

Comment: For anyone finding this thread - the install process has changed - see http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html

Comment: @RichardHollis Thank you: I have added the official link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems only available from Ubuntu 10.10. You can get the source with `git clone` and install it.

Answer (score 0):

*How do I fix the fact that it can't find the package?*

Gitolite is only available as package since Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick):
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gitolite

Like @VonC suggested, installing from Git / source is the way. Here's another link: http://eugenkiss.com/blog/2010/installing-redmine-gitolite-ubuntu-10.04/

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend going to the original source of gitolite on github and installing it from there.
Also you should really consider creating a separate user for git/gitolite
This is the official install document : http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/1-INSTALL.html
The same install document links to another excellent tutorial for installing gitoliste as non-root user, which I suggest you to follow http://sites.google.com/site/senawario/home/gitolite-tutorial